# PDO Inserting when table has default columns returns Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've created a database table of four columns, where two of the four are columns to not be updated. For example

Database columns:

- sessionID = auto increment mysql column
- userID = data to be passed in
- IP = data to be passed in
- timeSession = default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` in mysql column

So since two of these columns are to be filled with data, and two are not, I am only inserting the two values needed like so using PDO:

```
$d = [
   'userID' => $userID,
   'IP' => Helper::getIP()
];
$qry = "INSERT INTO {$this->tableName} VALUES (:userID,:IP)";
        $sth = $this->getConnection()->prepare($qry);
        $sth->execute($d);
```

When running this query, I get the following error: `Column count doesn't  match value count at row 1`. I have to manually set values for both `sessionID` and `timeSession` to make my insert work - which defeats the entire purpose of having an auto incrementing field and a field that auto populates in my database.

Do I have to modify my PDO logic to account for these two "special" tables? What am I missing here?

Comment: Why can't you just specify the columns you want to update? e.g. `INSERT INTO {$this->tableName} (userID, IP) VALUES (:userID, :IP)`

Comment: You appear to be missing the two columns you want to insert into : INSERT INTO {$this->tableName} (user_id,IP) VALUES (:userID,:IP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have four columns, but you specified only 2 in the `VALUES` section. You need to list their names after the table name and omit the ones which should be defaulted.

```
INSERT INTO {$this->tableName} (userID, IP) VALUES (:userID,:IP)
```

If you want to list the default columns, but let the values be defaulted then you can use the keyword `DEFAULT`

```
INSERT INTO {$this->tableName} (userID, IP, timeSession ) VALUES (:userID, :IP, DEFAULT)
```

> When inserting a new row, the default value for a column with an expression default can be inserted either by omitting the column name or by specifying the column as DEFAULT (just as for columns with literal defaults) - [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)

Comment: Your proposed solution works of manually setting `(userID, IP)`. Thanks.
But setting `timeAccessed` as `null` results in a `null` value in the column, resulting in the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` not being triggered.

Comment: Don't set `timeAccessed` to null. Let it default. As Dharman says, just specify the 2 columns you need to set. You may also use `SET userID=:userID,IP=:IP` as an alternate format.

Comment: @Dave the solution that @Dharman provides is perfect. 
But for knowledge, how would I set `timeAccessed` to default? In my array setting `timeAccessed => null` or `timeAccessed => ''` results in breaking the db column entry.

Comment: @ZachSmith I added an excerpt from the MySQL docs, however I would not recommend to list the columns names if you want them to default anyway. It adds noise to the query IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I like the alternative INSERT syntax that MySQL supports:

```
INSERT INTO {$this->tableName} SET userID = :userID, IP = :IP
```

It's easier to read, matches up the columns with the parameter placeholders, and it also solves the issue you're having when you don't want to specify a value for certain columns.

The downsides are:

- It's non-standard syntax, not supported by most other SQL brands.
- It doesn't support inserting multiple rows in a single INSERT statement.